# Can't create Angular JS module in Coffeescript

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, coffeescript

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
        <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    </div>


    <div ng-controller="SecondController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
        <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the following coffeescript:

```
window.myApp = angular.module 'myApp', []

myApp.factory 'Data', ->
    return message : 'I am data from a factory'

myApp.controller 'FirstController', ($scope, Data) ->
    $scope.data = Data

myApp.controller 'SecondController', ($scope, Data) ->
    $scope.data = Data
```

When I run the app, it prints out {{data.message}} instead of the text I type in the input box. When I remove the module dependency from the html and get data from a parent within the div, it works fine. This leads me to believe that the module is not getting created. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Try putting the script tag in the head after the library script.

Comment: Do you get any output on the JavaScript console?

Comment: @fncombo I don't know why it didn't work earlier, but it works now. If you submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the script tag that's in the `head` after the library script.